# Need help on aggregating data into a view (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, view

[image: view]

I'm new to using views, and I'm not exactly sure if what I want to do is possible using a view.

The first table is my original data file that I have imported into SQL.
I created a view with only the fruit and amount_from_us columns, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to include the amount in there.  Normally, I'd use a where clause, but I don't know how I can do that at the same time as selecting the other data.

Here is what I have so far:

```
CREATE VIEW fruit_summary AS
SELECT fruit
, SUM(amount) AS amount
FROM original_table
WHERE bought_from_us = 'yes'
GROUP BY fruit
```

This gets me the fruit column and the amount_from_us column.  I am however lost on how to get the date and total amount in there.  Is this even possible using views or should I just create a table and use joins?

Comment: Can you please elaborate what is your expected result and what are the columns you got... regards

Comment: My expected result is the table on the right, which has only instance of each fruit per day with the total amount and the total amount from us.

Comment: please check my answer bellow, I hope it will work... regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT fruit, 
       [date], 
       SUM(amount) AS amount, 
       SUM(case when bought_from_us = 'yes' then amount else 0 end)
                   AS amount_from_us
FROM original_table
GROUP BY fruit, [date]
```

Comment: Thank you!  I love the simplicity of this answer.  It does exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: @eek142 - Does it give you the last record Jan-17 Banana 0 0?

Comment: Oh, good catch.  It doesn't give me "Banana,0,0" but for now, I can live with that.  I actually will consider anything missing to be a zero, as there were no sales recorded that day in that item.

Answer (score 1):

```
create table #original_table
(
    [date] datetime,
    fruit varchar(50),
    amount money,
    bought_from_us char(3)
)

insert #original_table([date], fruit, amount, bought_from_us)
values ('01/18/2012', 'Apple', 10, 0);
insert #original_table([date], fruit, amount, bought_from_us)
values ('01/18/2012', 'Apple', 25, 'yes');
insert #original_table([date], fruit, amount, bought_from_us)
values ('01/18/2012', 'Orange', 32, 0);
insert #original_table([date], fruit, amount, bought_from_us)
values ('01/18/2012', 'Banana', 8, 0);
insert #original_table([date], fruit, amount, bought_from_us)
values ('01/18/2012', 'Banana', 235, 'yes');
insert #original_table([date], fruit, amount, bought_from_us)
values ('01/17/2012', 'Apple', 65, 0);
insert #original_table([date], fruit, amount, bought_from_us)
values ('01/17/2012', 'Apple', 4, 'yes');
insert #original_table([date], fruit, amount, bought_from_us)
values ('01/17/2012', 'Orange', 56, 0);
insert #original_table([date], fruit, amount, bought_from_us)
values ('01/17/2012', 'Orange', 95, 0);
```

What you've asked for in the result is quite complex. To get the last record, Jan-17 Banana 0 0, you need something like this:

```
with date_fruit_table as
(
    select date_table.[date], fruit_table.fruit
    from
        (select distinct fruit from #original_table) as fruit_table,
        (select distinct [date] from #original_table) as date_table
)

select date_fruit_table.[date], date_fruit_table.fruit,
    SUM(isnull(#original_table.amount, 0)) as amount,
    SUM(case #original_table.bought_from_us when 'yes' then #original_table.amount else 0 end) as amount_from_us
from date_fruit_table
left outer join #original_table on #original_table.fruit = date_fruit_table.fruit
    and #original_table.[date] = date_fruit_table.[date]
group by date_fruit_table.[date], date_fruit_table.fruit
order by date_fruit_table.[date] desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT fruit
, SUM(amount) AS amount
, SUM(amount_from_us) AS amount_from_us
, [Date]
FROM original_table
WHERE bought_from_us = 'yes'
GROUP BY fruit, [Date]
```

Comment: This, unfortunately, does not work because amount_from_us has no numerical values in it.  It is basically just a boolean.

Comment: Have you described its dayatype at the time when you raised the question!!!!!!! Its unfair to hit -1. Read what you answered me, "My expected result is the table on the right, which has only instance of each fruit per day with the total amount and the total amount from us".

Comment: That -1 wasn't from me.  I would never down-vote someone trying to help.  I actually don't have enough rep to down-vote yet anyway.

Answer (score 0):

sorry about my first answer, now I realize what you need:

```
with CTE_fruit as (
SELECT fruit, date, SUM(amount) AS amount, NULL AS amountUS
FROM original_table
GROUP BY fruit, date
union
SELECT fruit, date, NULL AS amount, SUM(amount) AS amountUS
FROM original_table
WHERE bought_from_us = 'yes'
GROUP BY fruit, date
)
select fruit, date, sum(amount), sum(amountUS) from CTE_fruit
GROUP BY fruit, date
```

I think this will work